# Neutrino oscillations

Tags: particle-physics, mass, frequency, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

It seems well documented that [neutrinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation) oscillate between flavours. In the link there are some figures which show probabilities but it isn't clear to me why the abscissa is measured in $L/E$. Is it meanigful to talk of the frequency of oscillation? Does the associated wavelength or energy, $\hbar \omega$, have any significance?

Comment: The answer to your question is in the link you provide: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation#Propagation_and_interference. what part of that is unclear?

Comment: @JEB I searched for frequency in the link but didn't see any details that answered my question. Could you point out the relevant section? Thanks.